# Как сделать эффект фингер-слайда по горизонтали?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не могу сделать медиа-слайдер. Хочу сделать эффект фингер-слайда с помощью мышки используя js или jquery.

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  height:100px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  width:100%;
}
.media_item{
  margin-right:10px;
  cursor:move;
}
.media_item img{
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
}
.image_slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3px;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 5px;
}
 
.image_slider::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background: transparent;
 border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.image_slider::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="row image_slider">

  <div class="media_item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="media_item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="media_item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="media_item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="media_item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Приведите ваш код

Comment: Есть же код....

Comment: Не получается сделать скролл для десктопных версий как на мобильных устройствах

Comment: Получается только с ползунком

Comment: Если вам просто надо что бы оно смещалось, то отслеживайте клик, запоминайте позицию курсора, вешайте маусмув и смещайте на разницу первоначальной позиции и текущей. Если вам нужно что бы это было с инерцией, то это задача не для SO и вообще лучше взять какой-то плагин тот же [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick)

Comment: Такие штуки как свайп, драг-н-дроп и подобные, на первый взляд несложны, но содержат много подводных камней. Поэтому я бы посоветовал поискать библиотеку для swipe с поддержкой мышки (такие есть, я использовал в реакт-проекте, но сейчас не вспомню).

Comment: Собсвенно, сверху уже посоветовали :)

Comment: Спасибо за отзывы. Помог плагин Slick. Работает отлично.